# Corrupted SD Card

Tags: ubuntu, corrupt

currently having a problem with rpi running ubuntu server. The rpi was disconnected without shutting it down, resulting in an error when trying to boot up after the disconnection.
I hooked it up to monitor and its saying:

```
0.3619991 Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
5.0661481 Failed to execute /init (error -2)
5.0714871 Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found,
5.0659141 CPU: O PID: 1 Comm: swapper/O Not tainted 5.11.0-1027-raspi #30-Ubuntu
Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/admin-guiderinit.rst for guidance
5.0936147 Hardware name: Raspherry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1 (DT)
5.0995451 Call trace:
5.1020271 dump_backtrace+0x0/Ox110
5.1057551
show_stack+0x24/0x30
5.1091221
dump_stack+OxfB/Ox164
5.1125811 panic+0x188/0x3b0
5.115686] kernel_init+0x110/0x130
5.1193221
ret_from_fork+0x10/0x3c
5.1229611 SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
5.1269521 Kernel Offset: 0x59f4d3c00000 fram OxffffB00010000000
5.133150] PHYS OFTSET: Ox?fffad1900000000
5.1374001 CPU Features: Ox00240022,61806000
5.1418301 Memory Limit: none
5.1449381
-I end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found. Try passing Init= option to kernel. See
init.rst for guidance.
```

I already tried running fsck on both partitions but no luck with that.

Could that be just an error with the partition and if so could I just replace the boot partition?

I already found a possible solution: [Forum Link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104606/how-to-handle-a-supposedly-corrupt-boot-partition)

But I am not sure about the reinstalling of the raspberrypi-kernel and raspberrypi-bootloader.
Are those the right packages or do I need to use ubuntu specific ones?

Comment: *"could I just replace the boot partition?"* -> This looks like the initramfs is corrupted, so yes **if** you are replacing it with the same boot partition as used on Ubuntu; the standard RpiOS/Raspbian one has no initramfs.  Download a fresh image from ubuntu and get it from there or cut that to a card and get it that way.

Comment: What does it mean when you say "no luck with that"? You don't have `fsck`? Or does it fail to run? Or does it give you an error message? Which one? Or does it perhaps find no error on your SD card?

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a comment to [@Dougie's answer (Forum Link)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104606/how-to-handle-a-supposedly-corrupt-boot-partition) - perhaps he'll have time to weigh in on your question here.

In the meantime, I'll offer this:

1. ***Don't mangle your SD card any further*** as it provides a (perhaps your only) backup for any files you may have created or modified on your Ubuntu system.
2. You asked, `"I am not sure about the reinstalling of the raspberrypi-kernel and raspberrypi-bootloader. Are those the right packages or do I need to use ubuntu specific ones?"`

   If you want to continue using Ubuntu on your RPi, I don't know if those raspberry-pi files will help or not. Hopefully, Dougie's recipe can be adapted to your Ubuntu installation; best to wait for him I think.
3. If Dougie's recipe doesn't work out, I think your course of action should be to re-install your Ubuntu system on a fresh, new SD card. Once you have it up and running, you will hopefully be able to mount your old SD card through a USB-adapter, and recover any files and folders.

[image: SD-USB adapter]

4. For the future: Your pain could have been avoided with a good backup. IMHO, the **best** backup system for RPi is the `image-utils` package created by RonR & [available from this forum post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=332000). But I don't know if `image-utils` supports Ubuntu. You might try asking RonR that question on the forum.

Comment: *"If you want to continue using Ubuntu on your RPi, those raspberry-pi files won't help."*  If those packages are actually available in Ubuntu, then chances are they will, since there is no reason for them to be there otherwise.  If they aren't available, then of course the point is mute.  They probably aren't, since there seems to be an initramfs in play which the standard Pi kernel does not use (there is not much point in a context where the kernel is compiled very specifically for the hardware, which a Pi kernel needs to be).